# Google Search Console lists recently added URL in excluded report but live test reports "URL is in Google"

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, coverage

About a week ago I added a new page and asked Google to index it using GSC.  My site typically takes a couple of weeks before Google ultimately adds it to any search query results, so I'm not expecting a quick indexing result.

However, I was looking at GSC - Coverage>Excluded pages today, and the page I just added last week, shows up in the "Excluded" list of pages.  When I use Google's "Test Live URL" it tests fine and says "URL is in Google... It can appear in Google Search results". I also looked for manual actions or security flag notices but don't show any in GSC.

So, my question is, is Google now adding new pages to the Excluded list until it "indexes" them, or should I be looking further into the page for problems?

**UPDATE:**
Okay, it's been just over a week since the page was submitted to Google.  Today, it's not in the excluded report.  I'll continue to watch for this to happen again.

Comment: It appears that there's a bug in Google Search currently that can be causing this issue:       http://feeds.seroundtable.com/~r/SearchEngineRoundtable1/~3/CALcOqC55UQ/google-search-canonical-url-issues-30180.html

Comment: @AndreGuelmann, thanks, but I think it's a different bug.  I wasn't aware of  the canonical issue, but I do see it now with other URLs after looking for it.

Comment: It appears that your site pages have some similar contents each other, in my experience, in this case, google excluded pages, but after all, google indexed all pages, you don't have to overworry.